# Recursive Generic Type Declaration in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

I'm a newbie to VB, and I am having difficulty understanding what the following (legacy code) class declaration actually means:

```
Public MustInherit Class ModelBase(Of T As {ModelBase(Of T, TIdType), New}, TIdType)
```

Can anyone explain the above?  There is also a related `ModelBaseCollection`:

```
Public MustInherit Class ModelBaseCollection(Of TCollection As {ModelBaseCollection(Of TCollection, TModel, TIdType), New}, TModel As {ModelBase(Of TModel, TIdType), New}, TIdType)
Inherits Collection(Of TModel)
```

I have difficulty understanding the need for the `ModelBaseCollection` class as the `ModelBase` class is a generic type.

Comment: Hmm... Recursive generics. If you understand C#, take a look at this: http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/09/23/recursive-generics-restrictions/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and generics constraints (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack of an answer for over 8 months, the comments referring to the *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* have been seen (correctly) as solutions.

Nevertheless, this can be explicitly described:

```
Public MustInherit
```

It is publicly accessible and cannot be created directly, but *must* be inherited to use;

```
 Class ModelBase(Of
```

It is a generic class where the specified classes are:

```
  T As {ModelBase(Of T, TIdType), New},
```

a creatable class inheriting from this class, and

```
  TIdType)
```

another type.

Without seeing the rest of the code, the `ModelBaseCollection` is just the same sort of construct, being able to refer to creatable versions of (an inherited class of) itself and the corresponding `ModelBase`.

Comment: Mark, thank you for taking the time to answer. +1, and accepted as the answer!