# Member with same type as class instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, data-structures, types

As title says, I'd like to know if it is possible.

I have a node class that points to another node in the same data structure.

```
class DataStructure<T, N>
  where T : IComparable<T>
  where N : Node<T> {
    N RootNode;

    // More code to follow, etc.
}

class Node<T>
  where T : IComparable<T> {
    T value;
    Node<T> NextNode;

    Node<T> GetLastNode() {
        Node<T> current = this;
        while (this.NextNode != null) {
            current = current.NextNode;
        }
        return current;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

I want to be able to expand the Node class though, in order to have more information for certain generic version of the `DataStructure`. For example:

```
class AdvancedNode<T> : Node<T>
  where T : IComparable<T> {
    int Height;
    int Size;
    // etc.
}
```

The problem with this is when I try to follow the `NextNode` link.

```
DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>> d = new DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>>();
d.RootNode = new AdvancedNode<char>();
d.RootNode.NextNode = new AdvancedNode<char>();
AdvancedNode<char> y = d.RootNode.NextNode;    // TYPE ERROR! Will not compile
```

Additionally, I want to make it so that it is not possible to do something like this:

```
DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>> d = new DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>>();
d.RootNode = new AdvancedNode<char>();
d.RootNode.NextNode = new Node<char>();    // This will compile, 
                                           // but I don't want it to!
```

Is there some way to enforce at build time that `Node.NextNode` will be the same type as `this`? I'd like to be able to implement a generic data structure without needing to do casting. Is it possible? Am I using an inferior design pattern?

Comment: I think it is dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c and other topics on [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: You missed to provide a definition of a non-generic `AdvancedNode` to us which is used in the example ..

Comment: @KenKin There is no non-generic AdvancedNode (the type is being inferred from the other type arguments as far as I can tell)

Comment: @KenKin changed it to DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>> to be more clear.

Comment: @Curtor: I guess what you are going to implement is like [LinkedListNode<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ahf4c754.aspx).

Comment: @KenKin This question originally came to mind when coding a base BinaryTree, and then wanting to expand on it to create a) a RedBlackTree where every node has a color, and b) an AvlTree where every node has a height, while still using the base BinaryTree functionality.

Comment: Did you consider using C5? It's well documented and comprehensive, covering most data structure needs. See http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/ and https://github.com/sestoft/C5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that should work is to use "Recursive generics" (See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c)).

We change the definition of `Node<T>` to `Node<N, T>` where `N` has to implement `Node<N, T>`...

```
abstract class Node<N, T>
    where N : Node<N, T>  // Here is the recursive definition
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T value;
    public N NextNode;

    public N GetLastNode()
    {
        N current = (N)this;
        while (this.NextNode != null)
        {
            current = current.NextNode;
        }
        return current;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Then, you just have to change the base class of `AdvancedNode<T>` to `Node<AdvancedNode<T>, T>`.

```
class AdvancedNode<T> : Node<AdvancedNode<T>, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int Height;
    int Size;
    // etc.
}
```

As well as the constraint on the type parameter `N` in the `DataStructure<T, N>` to `Node<N, T>`.

```
class DataStructure<T, N>
    where T : IComparable<T>
    where N : Node<N, T>
{
    public N RootNode;

    // More code to follow, etc.
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to instanciate directly a class using "recursive generic" because it would require to write something like: `Node<Node<Node<..., T>, T>, T>` if we want the correct types. This is why I made it abstract. To have a simple node, I've create a new type:

```
class SimpleNode<T> : Node<SimpleNode<T>, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
}
```

Comment: This is about as close as I got in attempting to have this, but unfortunately still requires a type cast whenever you want to return this as a result.

Comment: Where do you need a cast? In `Node<N, T>` (for example, with `N current = (N)this`;)? If it is the cast you are speaking about. I don't see any solution to avoid it. But it is also used to say (this must also inherit from `N`: this is why I made `Node<N, T>` abstract. Not to have the weird construction `Node<AdvancedNode<int>, int>` which must be forbidden).

Comment: Right, that was what I was trying to ask - is it possible to do this without casting. I understand this is a safe cast do to, but was curious if I was missing a way around it. It also means you need to do the same recursive definition with AdvancedNode if you want to have indefinite inheritance chains - SpecialNode<N, T> : AdvancedNode<SpecialNode<T>, T>

Comment: I have to admit, this reaches the limit of my knowledge! _Is it possible to do this without casting?_ I haven't found a solution for this, but it might be possible using a different structure for Node.  _It also means you need to do the same recursive definition with `AdvancedNode` if you want to have indefinite inheritance chains._ In that case, yes. But again, maybe there are other solutions for this that I don't know.

Comment: I think my answer is technically in the same sense as your, and there would not be a solution to get rid of something like `N current = (N)this;`, since a class cannot inherit from a type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VS around, but to me it looks like you should:

1. Change `Node<T>` to `Node<TData,TNode>` and declare the `NextNode` as a `Node<TData,TNode>`.
2. Declare `AdvancedNode` as `AdvancedNode<TData> : Node<TData,AdvancedNode<TData>>`.

This will ensure that subnodes are of same type as the root node. Replicate 2) for all other node types.

1. Move the `RootNode` property to `Node` (where it seems to belong more than with the data).
2. Change `DataStructure<T,N>` to `DataStructure<TNode>` (and infer `TData` from `TNode` if needed)

This will make the code cleaner (in terms of separation of concerns) and easier to understand, and may help you eliminate the need to have DataStructure depend on the node type, which would help simplify things. It doesn't strike me as good design to have the two generic types cross-dependent on each other, so if possible I'd aim for eliminating that.

Comment: Having a wrapping DataStructure allows for restricted access to the individual nodes; for example, if you wanted to keep track of every time a node was added, and have O(1) call to get the number of Nodes.

The first point is similar to what Cédric Bignon answered, but still has issues when you want to return this in the GetLast method.

Comment: @Curtor Made a few corrections, but will need VS to fiddle with the details ;) Have you considered using the visitor pattern instead of the wrapping? That is, pass in the node to the DataStructure for operations instead of having it as a class/type/constructor dependency.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, thanks for the alternative pattern suggestion. I'll have to experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

By your code, the only class which knows `N`, is `DataStructure<T, N>`. In the following elaboration, I'm using `TValue` instead of `T`, and `TNode` for `N`.

What you expecting are:

1. Constraint the node type which is passed to `DataStructure<TValue, TNode>`; so that `NextNode` for a node is also of the same type.
2. No extra casting needed

Then the best thing I can think of, is to make the node type a nested generic class, you are still able to constraint the type parameter be of it.

Since `IComparable<T>` is just a constraint of the value, which is irrelevant with your question, I take it off in the following code to make the code clear and more understandable, just add it back if you need.

- **Code**

  ```
  public partial class DataStructure<TValue, TNode>
          where TNode: DataStructure<TValue, TNode>.Node<TValue> {
      public partial class Node<T> {
          public TNode GetLastNode() {
              var current=this as TNode;

              for(; null!=current.NextNode; current=current.NextNode)
                  ;

              return current;
          }

          public TNode NextNode {
              set;
              get;
          }

          public TValue value {
              private set;
              get;
          }
      }

      public TNode RootNode;
  }

  public partial class AdvancedNode<TValue>
          : DataStructure<TValue, AdvancedNode<TValue>>.Node<TValue> {
      int Height;
      int Size;
  }
  ```

Note the expression of the while-loop in your original code `while(this.NextNode!=null) { current=current.NextNode; }` would cause a `NullReferenceException`.

By the code above, now you can test with the following test method which is a modified version from the original:

```
public static partial class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>> d=
            new DataStructure<char, AdvancedNode<char>>();

        d.RootNode=new AdvancedNode<char>();
        d.RootNode.NextNode=new AdvancedNode<char>();

        // type NO error! Will compile
        AdvancedNode<char> y=d.RootNode.NextNode;

        var rootNode=d.RootNode;
        var lastNode=rootNode.GetLastNode();
        Console.WriteLine("Is y the last node? "+(lastNode==y));
        Console.WriteLine("Is rootNode the last node? "+(lastNode==rootNode));
    }
}
```

Since `Node<T>` is a reference type, `==` is for comparing the reference and the result is as expected.

You can do the same thing with other classes which you are going to declare afterward.

Personally, I'd consider to use `LinkedList<T>` rather than implementing it myself. You're asking, hence an answer.

Comment: Why would while(this.NextNode!=null) { current=current.NextNode; } cause a  NullReferenceException? this cannot be null, and you don't de-reference the NextNode until you check it. your implementation of GetLastNode() essentially does the exact same thing.

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as Cédric Bignon's, where you can constrain the NextNode pointer, but still need to cast in order to return this. var current=this as TNode is essentially the same as doing a cast. I'm not sure what you benefit by placing the Node<T> class inside the DataStructure<TValue, TNode> class. The question is incredibly simplified from what I am trying to do (so that the question is concise and clear), hence why I don't just use LinkedList<T>.

Comment: @Curtor: You checked `this` for not being null, but use `current` for the assignment. The next time it loops, `current` can be null, and `current.NextNode` would cause NRE.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative may be to specify a composition to oppose to using inheritance. The disadvantage in this is that expanding on a specific composition would be more difficult.

For example, using the classes from the question:

```
class DataStructure<T, D>
  where T : IComparable<T> {
    Node<T, D> RootNode;

    // More code to follow, etc.
}

class Node<T, D>
  where T : IComparable<T> {
    T value;
    D data;
    Node<T, D> NextNode;

    Node<T, D> GetLastNode() {
        Node<T, D> current = this;
        while (current .NextNode != null) {
            current = current.NextNode;
        }
        return current;
    }

    // etc.
}

class AdvancedNodeData {
    int Height;
    int Size;
    // etc.
}

DataStructure<char, AdvancedNodeData> d = new DataStructure<char, AdvancedNodeData>();
d.RootNode = new Node<char, AdvancedNodeData>();
d.RootNode.NextNode = new Node<char, AdvancedNodeData>();
Node<char, AdvancedNodeData> y = d.RootNode.NextNode;
```