# "Covariance" in template parameters

Tags: c#

Let's say I have these two classes

```
class BaseClass 
{
    protected HashSet<BaseClass> container;
}


class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass() 
    {
        container = new HashSet<DerivedClass>(); 
    }
}
```

Then I receive an error: unable to convert.

Since every DerivedClass (should) be a BaseClass, I'm not quite sure why this error is being thrown, yet it is.

The goal is for BaseClass to perform a variety of operations on `container`, with only particularly specific behaviors tied to DerivedClass - among those, requiring that the container be of type `HashSet<DerivedClass>`.

How does this goal usually get accomplished?

Comment: Covariance is only allowed in interfaces. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx
I'd recommend reading the entire series.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a great architecture. Why would the base class mess around with its derived types? Why can't the set just be `new HashSet<BaseClass>()`?

Comment: Your design is not type safe.  If a method in `BaseClass` attempts to add an arbitrary instance of `BaseClass` to `container`, you'll have a type conflict.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: each derived class has to have the container specialized to it. This is a fairly kludgy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern .

Comment: Ok, accepted. I would still think about the importance of the set in the base class. Maybe an `IEnumerable` is sufficient which would be covariant.

Comment: A bit more expansion: the base class has a number of derived classes; the derived classes have a lot of commonality in functionality. But, critically, there only needs to be 1 of each derived class's variant information; no redundancy.  So the question is- how to be as DRY as possible. Note that BaseClass in this example would have methods that operate on Container.    It might be possible to have a FlyWeightDerivedClassFactory further out in the architecture where new DerivedClasses are instantiated to work around this, but that de-encapsulates things.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c (also may be slightly more than you need here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every `DevrivedClass` is a `BaseClass`, but not the other way around. `HashSet<T>` cannot be covariant since it allows write operations (`Add`). So in your scenario this would be possible:

```
class BaseClass 
{
   protected HashSet<BaseClass> container;

   public DoSomething()
   {
       container.Add(new BaseClass());   // not legal if container is really a List<DerivedClass>
   }
}
```

You could change the type of the container to be covariant:

```
class BaseClass 
{
   protected IEnumerable<BaseClass> container;
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   DerivedClass() 
  {
      container = new HashSet<DerivedClass>(); 
  }
}
```

But then only the derives class(es) could add items to `container` (which may work in your design).

You could also try making the base class generic:

```
class BaseClass<T> where T:BaseClass<T> 
{
   protected HashSet<T> container;
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
   DerivedClass() 
  {
      container = new HashSet<DerivedClass>(); 
  }
}
```

Which looks a little strange, but then again it looks strange for a class to contain a list of objects of the same type, so maybe in your real scenario it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is this:

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
   protected HashSet<T> container;
}


class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
   DerivedClass() 
  {
      container = new HashSet<DerivedClass>(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: This sort of relationship seems like a good example of when there is probably a better design that doesn't use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance is only supported for interfaces. That is, `container` must be declared as [ISet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx) (which inherits IEnumerable, which is covariant).

**EDIT**

As Nico says, this won't work as expected. To clarify why this is impossible, consider: `HashSet<BaseClass>.Add(DerivedClassA)` is a valid operation, but `HashSet<DerivedClassB>.Add(DerivedClassA)` is not. Therefore, `HashSet<DerivedClass>` *cannot be* a `HashSet<BaseClass>`.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is covariant, `ISet` is not because it allows read and write operations

Answer (score 0):

> A bit more expansion: the base class has a number of derived classes;
>   the derived classes have a lot of commonality in functionality. But,
>   critically, there only needs to be 1 of each derived class's variant
>   information; no redundancy. So the question is- how to be as DRY as
>   possible. Note that BaseClass in this example would have methods that
>   operate on Container. It might be possible to have a
>   FlyWeightDerivedClassFactory further out in the architecture where new
>   DerivedClasses are instantiated to work around this, but that
>   de-encapsulates things.

Consider creating a generic Container class which provides an interface for the base class to call its operations:

```
interface IContainer {
    void Operation1();
    void Operation2();
}

class Container<T> : IContainer where T : BaseClass {
    private HashSet<T> _internalContainer;

    ...
}

class BaseClass {
    protected IContainer container;
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    DerivedClass()  {
        container = new Container<DerivedClass>(); 
    }
}
```

All type-specific operations should be internal to `Container<T>` (or a class derived from it if necessary), while the interface methods are type-ignorant.