# Why can't I call a public method in the subclass from the superclass when the object is of the subclass type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class B that is a subclass of class A. I create an object of type B and  call OnlyA() on it, but inside OnlyA() the call to OnlyB() causes a compiler error.

From my understanding, `OnlyB()` is the same as `this.OnlyB()` and the method called should be chosen from the object's class (B), not the current class where code is being executed (A). This is why the call to Both() calls the method in B, not A. So why is it searching for OnlyB() in A, not B? How am I supposed to know when the method called is chosen from the object's class or the current class?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B bRefB = new B();

        bRefB.OnlyA();
    }
}

class A
{
    public void OnlyA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In A - OnlyA()");
        OnlyB(); // compiler error
        Both();  // calls the method in B
    }

    public virtual void Both()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In A - Both()");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void OnlyB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In B - OnlyB()");
    }

    public override void Both()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In B - Both()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine if you didn't get a compiler error. What good would static typing be? You'd be able to invoke literally anything from A and not get an error until runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely correct that `OnlyB` is the same as `this.OnlyB`. And that's the issue; `this` is of type `A`. It has no knowledge that `B` even exists (nor should it).

Superclasses do not, and are not supposed to, have any knowledge about the fact that they have derived classes *at all* let alone what methods are in them. Its not an issue of "searching"; what happens when you have `C` that doesn't define `OnlyB`? What method would be called?

Subclasses on the other hand are always subclasses of the super class; and so it is safe for them to invoke base class methods.

Comment: So the only way a superclass can call a method in the subclass (without using some advanced technique) is by calling a method that is overridden in the subclass? In other words, the superclass cannot access any subclass methods unless they override a method in the superclass?

Comment: @000 Correct; and that is the *only* technique that should be used to do such a thing. Note that you can use `abstract` instead of `virtual` to say that the base class does not define the behavior and force derived classes to implement it. This of course means the base class is no longer constructable

Answer (score 1):

Bradely's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834850/477420) covers why your code does not work (`this` is of type `A`). Here is correct way to write your requirements as code.

You want to call method based on run-time type of an object. Since compile time of `this` is type of the current object you need to cast it in some way to derived type before calling. Possible options:

- just cast - statically checked that B has `OnlyB`, cast exception at run-time:

  ```
  ((B)this).OnlyB();
  ```
- use `dynamic` - no static type checking, exception at run time if actual class does not have `OnlyB` method irrespective if it is from B, C...

  ```
  dynamic b = this;
  b.OnlyB();
  ```
- manual reflection call (same as `dynamic`).
- generics - see [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern and generics constraints (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c)