# How to resolve circular referencing in convoluted C# generics setup?

Tags: c#, generics

In order to save code, I tried setting up something like this:

```
namespace Base {
    class Application<CCOMPONENT1, CCOMPONENT2>
        where CCOMPONENT1 : Component1
        where CCOMPONENT2 : Component2 {
        public CCOMPONENT1 component1;
        public CCOMPONENT2 component2;
    }
    class Component<CAPPLICATION>
        where CAPPLICATION : Application {
        public CAPPLICATION application;
    }
    class Component1<CAPPLICATION> : Component<CAPPLICATION>;
    class Component2<CAPPLICATION> : Component<CAPPLCIATION>;
    ...
}
namespace Derived {
    class Application : Base.Application<Component1, Component2>;
    class Component1 : Base.Component1<Application>;
    class Component2 : Base.Component2<Application>;
    ...
}
```

Obviously, it's not working. When I specify the generic component types for the `Application` class, I have to specify the `Application` class as generic type, which in turn requires me to again specify the generic component types, and so on. Very much like a circular reference.

What I'd like to achieve is this: The `Base.Application` class shall contain references to `Base` components only, and
the `Base.Component` classes shall contain a reference to the `Base` application only.
However, the `Derived.Application` class shall contain references to `Derived` components,
and the `Derived.Component` classes shall contain a reference to the `Derived` application.

Although I have played around with generics for quite a while, I still can't wrap
my head around this problem. Is this even possible at all? Are there any workarounds
or maybe even cleaner approaches to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `Component1<CAPPLICATION>` and `Component2<CAPPLICATION>` are missing the `where CAPPLICATION : Application` and really do you need them?  Why not just do `class Component1 : Base.Component<Application>`?

Comment: Also might want to consider using the standard naming practice for generics where they start with a `T` to make it clear when a type is generic, like `class Application<TComponent1, TComponent2>`

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your problem, but I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327568/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-generics-constraints-c should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the pointers I got from the comments, I figured it out:

```
namespace Base {
    public class Application<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TAPPLICATION : Application<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT1 : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT2 : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> {
        public TCOMPONENT1 Component1;
        public TCOMPONENT2 Component2;
    }
    public class Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TAPPLICATION : Application<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT1 : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT2 : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> {
        public TAPPLICATION Application;
    }
    public class Component1<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TAPPLICATION : Application<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT1 : Component1<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT2 : Component2<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> {
    }
    public class Component2<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> : Component<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TAPPLICATION : Application<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT1 : Component1<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2>
        where TCOMPONENT2 : Component2<TAPPLICATION, TCOMPONENT1, TCOMPONENT2> {
    }
}
namespace Derived {
    public class Application : Base.Application<Application, Component1, Component2> {
        
    }
    public class Component1 : Base.Component1<Application, Component1, Component2> {
        
    }
    public class Component2 : Base.Component2<Application, Component1, Component2> {
        
    }
}
```

The key was to supply all generic types to all classes in the *Base* namespace. Looks a bit convoluted, but I can easily exchange components as I see fit in the *Derived* namespace, and in the I end I got exactly what I wanted.

Thanks!